# pygame not displaying my image

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

i started learning pygame and i followed some tutorials to make simple hello world project and it works  but when i do it my self trying to display my image on the window nothing happen!
this is my code

```
 __author__ = 'mohammed'
 import sys
 import pygame
 import color

 # -----------setup------------------------
 pygame.init()  # start pygame
 screensize = (800, 600)  # variable that we will use to declare screen size
 screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize)  # set the screen size

 pad = pygame.image.load('2.png')
 x = 100
 y = 100
 # -----------setup------------------------

 # -------------------main loop------------
 while 1:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             sys.exit()
     screen.blit(pad, (x, y))
     screen.fill(red)
     pygame.display.update()
```

i am importing my file that contain colors and their rgb :

```
red = (255, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're filling the screen after the image is drawn, covering the image. Try switching the order of the rows:

```
 screen.blit(pad, (x, y))
```

and

```
 screen.fill(red)
```